# How does one send blobs or arraybuffers through pusher?

Tags: pusher, pusher-js

The Pusher documentation [states](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/pusher-websockets-protocol/#websocket-data-messages) that it does not support binary websocket frames. Why is this the case and how would one send non-text data, e.g. blobs, through Pusher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a way to serialize your data in order to send it over. For binary data transmitted over text formats like JSON/XML, the most common way is to use `base64`.